# jQuery applying hover on pageload

Tags: jquery, hover

```
$("img").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass("move");
});
```

The situation is this: When you hover `img` a `.move` class is added to it (i.e. becoming `img.move` when hovered). This might be confusing to explain, but the problem is I need `.move` class to be added only if the `img` isn't already hovered on pageload.

To illustrate, let's pretend my site has a logo `img` that appears in the same spot on every page.

If a user hovers the logo, `.move` class is added to it (making the logo "move" around with css) Now the user clicks on the logo loading the homepage, but if their mouse is still on the logo when the new page loads, `.move` class is added making the logo move around again. I don't want the logo to "move around" if their mouse is already on the logo when the page loads. It should only "move around" if they hover the logo from somewhere else on the page.

**I need this:**

> (page loads) > (mouse is not hovered on `img`) > (then if mouse hovers
>   `img`) > (add `.move` class to `img`)

**But get rid of this:**

> (page loads) > (mouse is already hovered on `img`) > **!!!(add
>   `.move` class to `img`)!!! <-- Don't add `.move` if the mouse is
>   already on the `img`**

What's the best way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: i am a bit confused :P so if the cursor is NOT on top of the logo when the pageload happens then you want to change the class? and if it is already on top to do like nothing?

Comment: If the cursor IS on the logo when the page loads then do nothing.  That's it basically.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fiddle which will prevent the hover class from being added to an element, *and* make sure it is not added until the user moves the mouse away from the element and back again. It can probably be simplified some, but it proves the concept.

Test it by hovering the text, and press CTRL+Enter to run the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/PLP2d/2

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).one("mousemove", function() {
        $(".anch").hover(function() { $(this).hasClass("prevent") ? 0 : $(this).addClass("over");},
                         function() { $(this).removeClass("over") });

        if ($(".anch").is(":hover")) {
            $(".anch").addClass("prevent")
                      .removeClass("over")
                      .one("mouseleave", function() { $(this).removeClass("prevent") });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's the function I'm looking for and it works. But for some reason it doesn't work on latest Firefox? It's still "red" hover on pageload. Is it just me? Works on Google Chrome.

Comment: Good catch, Firefox apparently triggers the hover event when mouse is on an element to begin with. I solved it by moving the actual event bindings inside the mousemove event, so that no trigger of the hover/mouseenter is possible before the mouse has been moved once.

Comment: Sorry, can't test that from here, but I would guess that it's some similar problem. What happens in IE?

Comment: Same thing as the previous Firefox. Still "red" hover on pageload. Edit: I didn't test IE-10 previously before commenting on the Firefox issue. It didn't work on IE-10 before either; it has nothing to do with the new fiddle.

Comment: What have you tried to debug in IE? Does `.is(":hover")` work as expected on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
$(window).load(function(){ //when document + images are loaded

    if (!$('#yourimage').is(':hover')) {

       $('#yourimage').addClass('someclass'); 

       //add class to image if it's not hovered
       // on page load

    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AyAZx/417/

Comment: Basically, I don't want to add class if the hover is on the image on page load.

Comment: @Sunny Well, that's what it does. Try the fiddle.

Comment: It doesn't add the hover class later

Comment: @BalintBako The class that OP is asking for is added as long as you don't hover the image when it's loaded.

Comment: Not the same way I think: he wanted the class on the image on the next hover as the class is doing some sort of transition, quote : `(making the logo "move" around with css`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mousemove()](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event instead. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G75qb/2/)

```
$("img").mousemove(function(){
    $(this).addClass("move");
});
```